# SQLiteException: no such table: database-notes (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Tags: android, database, android-room, android-database

I'm trying to migrate a new database version. The only thing changed is an added column. I always get the following error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: database-notes (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE 'database-notes' ADD COLUMN image TEXT
```

I don't understand why I get this exception, because my table is named `database-notes` as written in the .build() call.

This is my database class:

```
@Database(
version = 2,
entities = [Note::class],
exportSchema = true)

abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun noteDao(): NoteDAO

companion object {
    fun build(context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "database-notes")
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).build()
    }
}

val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
       database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'database-notes' ADD COLUMN image TEXT")
    }
}
```

The database name was exactly the same in the previous version. I copied it to rule out typos.
What have I overlooked here? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because my table is named database-notes

It would appear not, due to the failure, and is probably a misunderstanding of the difference between the database name and table name(s).

A Database can have multiple tables. The database name is the name of the file itself (the container of the components such as tables, indexes, views and triggers).

In your code **database-notes**, as per the 3rd parameter to the Room.databaseBuilder is the name of the database (the file).

With Room the table names are derived from the classes that are both annotated with @Entity and provided, via the entities parameter of the @Database annotation. In your case the **Note** class.

The name of the table will be **Note** unless you use the `tableName =` parameter of the `@Entity` annotation to provide another name.

**Example**

If the following were your **Note** class :-

```
@Entity // No tableName parameter so the table name is the class name
data class Note(
    @PrimaryKey
    var noteId: Long? = null,
    var noteText: String,
    var image: String
)
```

Then the table name would be **Note** (the name of the class)

If the Note class were :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes") //<<<<< specifically names the table
data class Note(
    @PrimaryKey
    var noteId: Long? = null,
    var noteText: String,
    var image: String
)
```

The the table name would be **notes** (as specified by the `tableName =` parameter of the `@Entity` annotation).

Comment: Thank you very much, migration is working now. Rookie mistake :P